# $lookup in aggregation is very slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using `$lookup` to join two collections for counting, but `executionStats` shows that the query is very slow (500+ms per query for a single lookup). Here is the collection size:

```
> db.visit.find({}).count()
8174
> db.links.find({}).count()
89
```

Here is the lookup strage for the aggregation:

```
> db.visit.explain('executionStats').aggregate([{"$lookup": {from: "links", localField: "alias", foreignField: "alias", as: "url"}}])
```

results in:

```
{
    "stages": [
        {
            "$cursor": {
                "queryPlanner": {
                    "plannerVersion": 1,
                    "namespace": "redir.visit",
                    "indexFilterSet": false,
                    "parsedQuery": {

                    },
                    "queryHash": "8B3D4AB8",
                    "planCacheKey": "8B3D4AB8",
                    "winningPlan": {
                        "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                        "direction": "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans": []
                },
                "executionStats": {
                    "executionSuccess": true,
                    "nReturned": 8174,
                    "executionTimeMillis": 642,
                    "totalKeysExamined": 0,
                    "totalDocsExamined": 8174,
                    "executionStages": {
                        "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                        "nReturned": 8174,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                        "works": 8176,
                        "advanced": 8174,
                        "needTime": 1,
                        "needYield": 0,
                        "saveState": 9,
                        "restoreState": 9,
                        "isEOF": 1,
                        "direction": "forward",
                        "docsExamined": 8174
                    }
                }
            },
            "nReturned": NumberLong(8174),
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": NumberLong(7)
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "links",
                "as": "url",
                "localField": "alias",
                "foreignField": "alias"
            },
            "nReturned": NumberLong(8174),
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": NumberLong(643)
        }
    ]
}
```

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Better schema! MongoDB is not a relational database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pipeline does not have any filtering in the first stage, so when you execute the aggregation the implicit first step is "fetch all documents from the visit collection"

Each document is then passed into the pipeline, and the `$lookup` stage executes a find query on the "links" collection for each one.

If you don't have an index on `{alias: 1}` in the links collections, it will have to examine every document in that collection to fetch any that match the "alias" field from the source document.

In the unindexed case, this means that the aggregation query will need to examine each of those 89 links documents 8174 times, for a total of 727486 document examinations. Each examination would involve a string comparison (assuming "alias" is a string) of 1 field from each document.

With a total runtime of 643 milliseconds, that averages to ~1131 documents examined per millisecond, which means 1 string comparison per microsecond.

That actually doesn't sound too bad.

If you want it to perform faster, minimize the number of documents examined.

There are 2 main ways this might be accomplished:

- don't use aliases, put the link information directly in the "visit" document.
  This would completely eliminate the need for a $lookup during the fetch, at the expense of doing the lookup while writing the "visit" document
- create an index on `{ alias: 1 }` in the "links" collection
  This will replace the 89 * 8174 document examinations by and 8174 index scans, followed by examining only the documents with a matching alias.  Assuming that each "visit" contains only 1 alias, and the each alias exists in only one "links" document, this would reduce the total from 727486 document examinations to 8174 index scans + 8174 document examination.